# Change default indent size in mail.app

Tags: mail.app, plist, formatting

My mail.app seems to default to a barbaric 8-space indent-size.  Is there anyway to change this (e.g. is there a plist file somewhere that includes this specification)?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**This is normal.**

(It cannot be changed)

The [standard tab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key) size for an 80 column page (typewriter or console) is 8 spaces.

You also must remember, that email is for sending *correspondence* (letters)  and indentation here is "old fashioned."  In other words, you shouldn't be indenting in your letter writing.

- [What Is an Indented Letter Style?](https://www.reference.com/world-view/indented-letter-style-d52b7180a4f6a1b0)
- [How to Write a Letter](https://www.artofmanliness.com/articles/how-to-write-a-letter/)

In the second link, you do indent, it should be 1" and that is approximately 8 characters.